# Combining 3 Arrays into one custom line of text

Tags: arrays, swift, merge

I'm creating a baking app and I'm stuck at a simple task… But can't figure out how to solve it.

I basically have 3 Arrays:

```
let quantity = [200, 300, 400]
let value = ["g", "g", "kg"]
let ingredient = ["Flour", "Butter", "Chocolate"]
```

What I want is to display those 3 arrays in text like this:

```
200 g Flour - 300 g Butter - 400 kg Chocolate
```

I've tried the following:

```
let arrays = [value, ingredient]
let merge = (0..<arrays.map{$0.count}.max()!).flatMap{i in arrays.filter{i<$0.count}.map{$0[i]}}
let text = merge.joined(separator: " - ")
```

which results in :

```
g - Flour - g - Butter - kg - Chocolate
```

Does anybody know how to achieve it?
It is probably very simple but I'm not seeing it…

Comment: It might be better to create a top-level struct for this instead of maintaining 3 separate arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a top-level struct for holding all these elements. Dealing with arrays and its indices is risky and not very *clean*. With your current approach you have to maintain 3 separate arrays - what if you forget to add an element to one of them?

Instead you can try the following:

```
struct Ingredient: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String
    let quantity: Int // may be Double as well
    let unit: Unit
    
    var description: String {
        "\(quantity) \(unit.rawValue) \(name)"
    }
}

enum Unit: String {
    case gram = "g"
    case kilogram = "kg"
}

let ingredients = [
    Ingredient(name: "Flour", quantity: 200, unit: .gram),
    Ingredient(name: "Butter", quantity: 300, unit: .gram),
    Ingredient(name: "Chocolate", quantity: 400, unit: .kilogram)
]

let description = ingredients.map(String.init).joined(separator: " - ")
print(description) 
// prints "200 g Flour - 300 g Butter - 400 kg Chocolate"
```

Comment: Use of description is discouraged `map(String.init)`

Comment: btw `let ingredients = [("Flour",200,.gram),  ("Butter", 300, .gram),  ("Chocolate",  400, .kilogram)].map(Ingredient.init)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Nice, thanks :) I didn't know I can do that.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thank you so much! Actually had all the elements but couldn't figure out how to put them together :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
let quantity = [200, 300, 400]
let value = ["g", "g", "kg"]
let ingredient = ["Flour", "Butter", "Chocolate"]

var str = ""
for index in quantity.indices {
    str += "\(quantity[index]) \(value[index]) \(ingredient[index]) - "
}

let result = str.dropLast(3)
print(result)
```

Result:
`200 g Flour - 300 g Butter - 400 kg Chocolate`

Answer (score 0):

If you **have** to handle 3 arrays this way then it would be a good idea to use nested `Zip2Sequence` because it will be safer when dealing with arrays of different length.
Ideally you would expect all arrays to be of same length but what if... just what if they aren't.

```
let quantity = [200, 300, 400]
let value = ["g", "g", "kg"]
let ingredient = ["Flour", "Butter", "Chocolate"]

let zippedQuantity = zip(quantity, value)
let result = zip(zippedQuantity, ingredient).map { (quantityZip, ingredient) in
    "\(quantityZip.0) \(quantityZip.1) \(ingredient)"
}

let string = result.joined(separator: " - ")
print(string)
```

---

<sub>Sadly there is no `Zip3Sequence` to make this even quicker</sub>